# Custom harmless equalizer settings

Tags: hearing, ear, cellular-phone

I recently bought a new phone. I didn't like audio quality so I went to Equalizer and changed the settings to these:

[image]

I know high frequencies are harmful. So, is this setting okay? Please note that this is a setting for listening WITHOUT headphones/earphones. With those, normal default equalizer settings are used by my phone.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE.  It is very difficult to answer a question like this as it is very specific to your phone, environment and other factors.

Comment: I have to agree with @ChrisRogers. Volume is a major component, for example, and we know nothing about the volume settings, how close you hold the phone to your ear, etc. You're also asking for medical advice, which is strictly off topic here.

Comment: I didn't find another server suitable site for asking about this. the volume is not too high, probably medium, and the phone is being held at reading distance (like 40 cm) or maybe further.

Comment: Please read the link in the closure notice. Whatever settings you used are irrelevant here because you're asking for medical advice and we don't provide that here.